# MassTransit Custom MessageType Name

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

We've been using MassTransit to act as a ServiceBus between our microservices.

We have on microservice in python and the other in .Net, in this case the python service publish a message like so `bus.publish('x.y.z', message)`

And of course the .Net side has a type of `x.y.z`, we want to change the namespace of `x.y.x` to `a.b.c` and still let the system to work without changing the python side.

I've tried `cfg.Message<A.B.C>(x => x.SetEntityName("x.y.z"));`

But it does not work, i can see the message in the queue and that someone reads it but no consumer is triggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the serialized message envelope (in JSON) to see how the message should be formatted (from Python, or any other language) and include the message types (using the type name formatting style required by MassTransit) in the envelope.

See this page in the documentation for details: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/interoperability.html

It isn't just the entity name, that's for publishing and subscribing, but you need to look at the actual types in the envelope to be able to deserialize the message by a consumer.

Comment: Hi @Chris thank for the reply, so by your statement above i can understand that in the python side i am always coupled to the namespace of dotnet type ?